# Align Title To Each Number in Javascript Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, css

How do you center align each span over each Day, Hour, Min, Sec? Currently just adding padding to the text but it doesn't align to it's respective number. And when any number column goes to single digits it shifts the numbers.

Pen: https://codepen.io/zepzia/pen/MmoVJm

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 7, 2017 12:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " " +
    minutes + " " + seconds + " ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_AQ0vcRxFu0A/S9shDGGyMTI/AAAAAAAAAYk/kn3WTkY2LoQ/s1600/IMG_0714.JPG);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.countdown-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

#countdown,
#countdown-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#countdown {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 142px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .7;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
}

#countdown-text {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  opacity: .8;
}

.counter-text {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="countdown-wrapper">
  <div id="countdown"></div>
  <div id="countdown-text">
    <span class="counter-text">DAYS</span>
    <span class="counter-text">HOURS</span>
    <span class="counter-text">MINS</span>
    <span class="counter-text">SECS</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use separate `div` elements for each day, hr, min, sec. that will give you more control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar to [TxRegex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43745767/4760460). I've restructured your html, made some adjustments to your css and in your javascript I've replaced:

```
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " " +
minutes + " " + seconds + " ";
```

with:

```
document.getElementById("daysTicker").innerHTML = days;
document.getElementById("hoursTicker").innerHTML = hours;
document.getElementById("minsTicker").innerHTML = minutes;
document.getElementById("secsTicker").innerHTML = seconds;
```

to place them in the newly created divs.

Here's the [updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyLrmz).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than put your countdown numbers that update dynamically into a single div, create a seperate div for days, hours, minutes and seconds.

```
<div class="countdown-wrapper">
    <div class="countdown-chunk">
        <div class="counter-value" id="daysValue"></div>
        <div class="counter-label">DAYS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-chunk">
        <div class="counter-value" id="hoursValue"></div>
        <div class="counter-label">HOURS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-chunk">
        <div class="counter-value" id="minutesValue"></div>
        <div class="counter-label">MINUTES</div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-chunk">
        <div class="counter-value" id="secondsValue"></div>
        <div class="counter-label">SECONDS</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you align each countdown-chunk with flexbox and make sure to add text-align: center to the countdown-chunk as well. You can style counter-value and counter-label independently.

```
.countdown-chunk {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.countdown-wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You also have 4 elements to update instead of just one, but that is easy compared to trying to align disjointed elements.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
        .row {
           display: -webkit-flex;
           display: flex;
           -webkit-flex-direction: row;
           flex-direction: row;
        }

        .column {
           display: -webkit-flex;
           display: flex;
           -webkit-flex-direction: column;
           flex-direction: column;
        }


        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="column">
              <div class="counter-text" id="days"></div>
              <div class="counter-text" id="hours"></div>
              <div class="counter-text" id="minutes"></div>
              <div class="counter-text" id="secs"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <div class="counter-text">DAYS</div>
              <div class="counter-text">HOURS</div>
              <div class="counter-text">MINUTES</div>
              <div class="counter-text">SECS</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        //javascript
         document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days ;
         document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours ;
         document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes ;
         document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = secs ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to restructure your HTML a bit so that the number and the label are in the same containing element. This lets you put a "box" around them so that they always line up. Here's one way to do that:

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 7, 2017 12:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("counter-days").innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById("counter-hours").innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById("counter-mins").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById("counter-secs").innerHTML = seconds;

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_AQ0vcRxFu0A/S9shDGGyMTI/AAAAAAAAAYk/kn3WTkY2LoQ/s1600/IMG_0714.JPG);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.countdown-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

#countdown {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#countdown > div {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.counter-num {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 142px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: .7;
  letter-spacing: -4px;

}

.counter-text {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="countdown-wrapper">
  <div id="countdown">
    <div id="countdown-days">
      <span class="counter-num" id="counter-days"></span>
      <span class="counter-text">DAYS</span>
    </div>
    <div id="countdown-hours">
      <span class="counter-num" id="counter-hours"></span>
      <span class="counter-text">HOURS</span>
    </div>
    <div id="countdown-mins">
      <span class="counter-num" id="counter-mins"></span>
      <span class="counter-text">MINS</span>
    </div>
    <div id="countdown-secs">
      <span class="counter-num" id="counter-secs"></span>
      <span class="counter-text">SECS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```